# jquery search and replace text from nth occurrence

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

```
Input data = '/hello/world/test'
```

I need output like `'hello-world-test'` in jquery.

I have tried splice,replace method and also a customize condition(sample code below). But still im not able to get the result.

```
var split_data=data.split('/');
var new_data='';
        $.each(split_data,function(x){
            if(x!=0){
                new_data=split_data[x]+'-'
            }
        });
        console.log("new"+new_data); // Output : hello-world-test-
```

Here again I have to remove the last hypen in the output string. So is there anyway to accomplish my output.

By the way Im not expert in jquery.

Comment: Have a look at this URL. you need to replace all occurenences and then take substring from position '1' to length -1 of a string. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use regex and `slice` the first char:

```
str = str.slice(1).replace(/\//g,'-');
```

[replace on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PEC4B/)

<sub>You really shouldn't use jQuery for string manipulations</sub>

Comment: this will give output as '-hello-world-test', but i dont want that hyphen at index 0

Comment: @PSivachandran, sorry, I didn't see the first hyphen. Fixed.

Comment: Efficient answer its what I was going to suggest